# SQLAlchemy, add records with foreign key constraints dependency

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I am new to Flask-SQLAchemy and SQLAlchemy, trying to understand constraints and relationships, so I wrote the below code from a well known database example. Each Employee instance belongs to a Department, and each Department instance has an Employee as manager. Both foreign keys, dnumber and mgrssn, cannot be null. The code works as expected and creates the exact same schema produced by SQL code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "public"})
    ssn = db.Column('ssn', db.String(11), primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column('fname', db.String(20), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column('lname', db.String(20), nullable=False)
    bdate = db.Column('bdate', db.Date, nullable=False)
    address = db.Column('address', db.String(50), nullable=False)
    sex = db.Column('sex', db.String(1), nullable=False)
    salary = db.Column('salary', db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Relationship (1-1): Employee --has-> Employee (as supervisor)
    superssn = db.Column('superssn',
                         db.String(11),
                         db.ForeignKey('public.employee.ssn', name='supervisor'))
    emp_supervisor = db.relationship('Employee', backref=db.backref(name='supervisor', remote_side=ssn), lazy='dynamic')

    # Relationship (1-M): Department --has-> Employee(s)
    dnumber = db.Column('dnumber',
                        db.Integer,
                        db.ForeignKey("public.department.dnumber", name='department'),
                        nullable=False)

    # Relationship (1-M): Employee(manager) --manages-> Department(s)
    dep_manager = db.relationship('Department', backref='manager', lazy='dynamic', foreign_keys="[Department.mgrssn]", post_update=True)


class Department(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "department"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "public"})
    dnumber = db.Column('dnumber', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    dname = db.Column('dname', db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # Relationship (1-M): Employee(manager) --manages-> Department(s)
    mgrssn = db.Column('mgrssn',
                       db.String(11),
                       db.ForeignKey("public.employee.ssn", name='manager'),
                       nullable=False,
                       unique=True)

    mgrstartdate = db.Column('mgrstartdate', db.Date, nullable=False)

    # Relationship (1-M): Department --has-> Employee(s)
    employees = db.relationship('Employee', backref='department', lazy='dynamic', foreign_keys="[Employee.dnumber]", post_update=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Department> {self.dname}'
```

The problem starts when I am trying to insert rows, while I cannot find the correct order of creating and updating the instances given the constraints. I have made several tests, as the one below, which returns the obvious error:
"*sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "dnumber" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (888-66-5555, James E, Borg, 1937-11-10, 450 Stone,. Houston, TX, M, 55000, 888-66-5555, null).*"

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    db.create_all()

    emp1 = Employee(ssn='888-66-5555', fname='James E', lname='Borg', bdate='1937-11-10', address='450 Stone,. Houston, TX', sex='M', salary=55000, superssn='888-66-5555')
    dep1 = Department(dnumber=5, dname='Research', mgrstartdate='1998-05-22')
    emp1.department = dep1
    db.session.add(emp1)
    dep1.manager = emp1
    db.session.add(dep1)
    db.session.commit()
```

Using SQL syntax with `WITH xxx AS INSERT` I can control the order of insert statements. However, I cannot find how to achieve that in SQLAlchemy, when the foreign keys exist in both related tables?